# System.Timers.Timer и DateTime: Почему выводятся начальные значения?

Tags: c#, .net

По идее каждую секунду должно выводить новые значения, но выводит начальные. С DateTime.Now работает верно. В чем фишка?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DateTime d1;
        public static DateTime d2;

        private static void TimerEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            d1.AddSeconds(1);
            d2.AddSeconds(-1);
            Console.WriteLine(d1);
            Console.WriteLine(d2);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Timer timer1 = new Timer(1000);
            timer1.AutoReset = true;
            d1 = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 37);
            d2 = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 57, 11);
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEvent);
            timer1.Start();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @WarHamster, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: черт, ошибка первоклассника..)) спасибо)

Comment: @Котик: опубликуйте как ответ! Подобные вопросы вопросы часто задаются (по крайней мере на stackoverflow), можно будет направлять сюда авторов с похожими проблемами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d1 = d1.AddSeconds(1);`
`d2 = d2.AddSeconds(-1);`

Comment: Фишка в том, что метод `AddSeconds` не изменяет текущий экземпляр `DateTime`, а возвращает новый.

Comment: @Modus: я бы сказал, фишка в том, что структуры в .NET имеют семантику значения и следовательно неизменяемы. (В большинстве случаев: мутабельную структуру написать можно, но не нужно.)